# best way to write this on iphone

Tags: iphone

this is the output i want
**"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%love%' or desc like '%love%'";**

where **love is a text enterted by use**r 
now i want to write this in effective way
right now i am doing this lame code

```
    myStringPrt1=@"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%"

    NSString *trimmedString1 = [myStringPrt1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    myStringPrt2=UserText;// user input LOVE
    NSString *myStringPrt3=@"%' or desc like '%";
    NSString *myStringPrt4=@"%'";


    trimmedString1=[trimmedString1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt2];

    trimmedString1=[ trimmedString1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt3];
    trimmedString1=[ trimmedString1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt2];
    trimmedString1=[ trimmedString1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt4];
    NSLog(@"My string is  now =  %@", trimmedString1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* SQL_statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%@%%' or desc like '%%%@'", UserText, UserText];
```

Comment: nope 
this is your output
SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like 'SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%' or desc like '%SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like 'SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%' or desc like '%'

Comment: still i am getting something :)

Comment: i have to add "" also to make query complete 
"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%love%' or desc like '%love%'"

Comment: well then do not use `UserText`, this seems to be a property. Use the `myStringPrt2` instead. Will give you `NSString* SQL_statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%@%%' or desc like '%%%@'", myStringPtr2, myStringPtr2];`

Comment: perfect hoew about adding " in begining and at end "

Comment: i cant add " at begining and " at end of this string

Comment: c'mon, it's just like this `"\"qoted\""`

Comment: am very close but its not working
@"""SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%%%@%%' or desc like '%%%@%%'", myStringPrt2, myStringPrt2];
 i am out of mind :(

Comment: are you reading my comments? you have to escape the double quote to put it inside a string.
`@"\"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%%%@%%' or desc like '%%%@%%'\""`

Comment: u really help me thanks a lot 

but stil i dont knw why my query is not working andy way you did your best :-)

const char *sqlStatement = SQL_statement;//"SELECT * FROM wateat_tbl where name like '%love%' or desc like '%love%' ";

Comment: is that because char to string??

Comment: `const char *sqlStatement = [SQL_statement UTF8String];`

Comment: amazing you saved my life one beer to you and hats of  you are wonderfull :-)  i am glad  i have no words for you keep this spirit to help others :-) have a nice day

Comment: let me suggest that you mark the post as an answer, will do for a beer ;)